# PHP regex with preg_replace and the "." character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have scientific names in the following format:

```
S. daemon
A. cacatuoides
B. splendens
```

Etc, etc.

I'm having difficulty with the "." character.

This code works for full species names (i.e. `Satanoperca daemon`):

```
  foreach ($species as $term) {
    $term_norm = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(trim($term)));
    $pattern[] = preg_replace('/ /', '\\s+', preg_quote($term_norm));

    $urls[$term_norm] = '/dev/species/' . str_replace(" ", "-", rawurlencode($term));
    $rels[$term_norm] = $urls[$term_norm] . '?preview=true';
    $title[$term_norm] = $term;
```

But I can't get it to work for the aforementioned examples:

```
    $genus_species = explode(" ", $term);
    $genus = $genus_species[0];
    $species = $genus_species[1];
    $initial = substr($genus, 0, 1);
    $shortened = $initial . '. ' . $species;

    $term_norm = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(trim($shortened)));
    $pattern[] = preg_replace('/ /', '\\s+', preg_quote($term_norm));

    $urls[$term_norm] = '/dev/species/' . rawurlencode($term);
    $rels[$term_norm] = $urls[$term_norm] . '?preview=true';
    $title[$term_norm] = $term;
```

If I use this code, nearly all of my source, i.e. every word/character, is linked with `<a href=""></a>`. If I comment the code out, the full name linking works perfectly and not such problem occurs.

---

**A little more info...**

`$pattern` is echoing out as: `/\b(SATANOPERCA\s+DAEMON|S(\.)\s+DAEMON)\b/i`

The input is a list of species names, such as the ones I previously mentioned. The source is a species profile, which often refers to other species.

What I'd like the code to do is replace any mention of these species names with a link to that species profile.

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have not given any example what this should to which might be helpful to find out what's going wrong ;) For debugging purposes you could echo the patterns you try to match and then look into them if you can spot the problem.

Comment: Apologies - I think I rushed the question somewhat. Have added a little further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking into your issue I ran over the way you initially build the regular expression. I thought, why not simplify it? Here is what I've come up with:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    list($genus, $species) = explode(' ', $term);
    $pattern = sprintf('~\b((?:%s[.]|%s) %s)~i', $genus[0], $genus, $species);
```

Which gives the following

```
~\b((?:S[.]|Satanoperca) daemon)~i
```

I'm making use of [`list`](http://php.net/list) here in combination with `explode` which often is less code, so better readable.

To build the regular expression I use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) which often is easier to formulate complex strings you need substitution in. It allows the usage of a mask.

Finally `$genus[0]` is the first character of `$genus`. You might need to replace it in case you're using a multibyte character set. Just saying.

The pattern itself is streamlined as well:

```
~\b((?:S[.]|Satanoperca) daemon)~i
```

The first subgroup is non-catching (`?:`) and offers both variants: Short with `.` or the long genus. Then followed by the space and finally the species. I also use `[.]` to express the dot in there, but sure `\.` would work as well:

```
~\b((?:S\.|Satanoperca) daemon)~i
```

What's left is the replacement procedure. I opted for using a callback function here. As the link needs only be build once for the term, I add that on top of the foreach. Again I'm using `sprintf` to format it:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $termSlug = strtolower(strtr($term, array(' ' => '-')));
    $termHref = sprintf('/dev/species/%s', rawurlencode($termSlug));
    list($genus, $species) = explode(' ', $term);
    $pattern = sprintf('~\b((?:%s\.|%s) %s)~i', $genus[0], $genus, $species);
```

What's left is the callback function that replaces every match with the link:

```
    $string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use($term, $termHref)
    {
        return sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $termHref
            , htmlspecialchars($term), htmlspecialchars($match[1]));
    }, $string);
```

And that's it. The full example:

```
$string = <<<STR
S. daemon
Satanoperca daemon
A. cacatuoides
B. splendens
STR;

$terms = array(
    'Satanoperca daemon',
);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $termSlug = strtolower(strtr($term, array(' ' => '-')));
    $termHref = sprintf('/dev/species/%s', rawurlencode($termSlug));
    list($genus, $species) = explode(' ', $term);
    $pattern = sprintf('~\b((?:%s\.|%s) %s)~i', $genus[0], $genus, $species);
    echo $pattern, "\n";
    $string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use($term, $termHref)
    {
        return sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $termHref
            , htmlspecialchars($term), htmlspecialchars($match[1]));
    }, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

And it's output:

```
<a href="/dev/species/satanoperca-daemon" title="Satanoperca daemon">S. daemon</a>
<a href="/dev/species/satanoperca-daemon" title="Satanoperca daemon">Satanoperca daemon</a>
A. cacatuoides
B. splendens
```

I hope this is helpful even it's completely new code everywhere.

---

**Validate Terms:**

```
// validate terms
$valid = '/^\w+ \w+$/';
foreach ($terms as $index => $term) {
    if ($result = preg_match($valid, $term))
        continue;
    printf("Invalid Term: (%d) %s\n", $index, $term);
}
```

Comment: Hell of an answer Sir, thank you very much! I'll be giving this a go tonight or, if not, the next couple of days. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Ah, one question hakre. I'm having a bit of an issue with some entries like `C. popelini` where the `C.` bit (and not the `popelini`) is being linked to the `Centromochlus perugiae` profile - and it's adding an extra hyphen into the URL (`/species/centromochlus--perugiae/`). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: if you can add some sample data I might be able to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks mate. Pattern here: http://pastebin.com/uVBigPQh and example source here: http://pastebin.com/rk0kDdek

Comment: @dunc: I meant more the input text (or a fraction of it with the problematic area) and a list of the terms (or a fraction of it) so I can actually run the procedure (test against data). I don't have a list of such terms, only had those three you provided in question.

Comment: Ah, sorry! Source here: http://pastebin.com/GJrxwq5s and terms here: http://pastebin.com/KimsXyKB

Comment: @dunc: That's something to work with. 129 of your terms do not match the specification of the terms you have given (two words separated by a single space): http://pastebin.com/ziLWFKft . These preconditions have not been checked so far in the code, so this could trigger problems. Those are invalid because `\b` checks for a word boundary and the splitting is done with the space. The new use-case needs are more differentiated handling, it's not that simple as you have outlined in your question.

Comment: I'm happy enough to exclude those from the filter if that's the easiest way to adapt the code @hakre. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dunc: Added some code chunk I used to validate your input terms. Hope this gives you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to include the `.` also like this

```
$term_norm = preg_replace('/[\s\.]+/', ' ', strtoupper(trim($shortened)));
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for that. I've tried using this code but nothing changes.